# Activate virtualenv for git command in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, githooks

I have a Python project on a Vagrant virtual machine (ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS) and I use Visual Studio Code to develop on it with the Remote SSH extension.

When I launch `git commit` I need to run it inside a virtual environment because there is a git hook that needs it.

In the workspace config file I have set `"python.pythonPath"` key, but it seems that is ignored from git.

How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: I do not think it is the pythonPath, I have it set up correctly.

Comment: on my case, my git is on my system level & I am using virtualenv. So when the vscode git try to do git hooks it can not find all the packages it needs. There is no way to make the vscode source control to activate virtualenv first

Comment: See [microsoft/vscode-pytho#10165](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10165) on GitHub

Answer (score 2):

Just add `. /path/to/your/python/virtual_env/bin/activate` into your git hooks files:

```
.git/hooks/pre-commit
.git/hooks/pre-push
.git/hooks/post-checkout
```

in your case, the resulted `.git/hooks/pre-commit` may looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
. ./venv/bin/activate
exec dvc git-hook pre-commit $@
```

The `. ./venv/bin/activate` means source virtual environment.